# How to print summary on gridview footer

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I want to count a `Gridview` column data with a condition.  (i.e. where column data="Yes" then only count) But  the `Gridview`  is auto generated.   Number of columns and rows are changing frequently.

How to count the column data and print at footer

Like this.....

Total no of Yes =18 total no of No =2

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to implement. You need to use the `OnRowDataBound` function of your gridview.

Some Pseudocode below as you have not provided your gridview structure

```
protected void gridviewID_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int totalyes=0;
    int totalno=0;
    for(int i=0;i<gridviewID.Columns.Count;i++)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Assuming the column containg yes or no is the third column.
            if( e.Row.Cells[i].Text.ToLower()=="yes")
            {
                totalyes++
            }
            else
            {
                totalno++;  
            }
        }
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].Text="Total Yes: "+ totalyes.ToString() + "Total No: "+totalno.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: protected void summary_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
// I want to use e.Row.Cells[i].Text instead of e.Row.Cells[5].Text 
if (e.Row.Cells[5].Text == "Yes")
{
totalyes++;
}
}
               
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{ // I want to use e.Row.Cells[i].Text instead of e.Row.Cells[5].Text 
e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "Total no. of Yes: " + totalyes.ToString();
}
}

Comment: Basically what I am trying is, I want to summarise all column data(Text data) in respective columns footers.     The number of columns are not fixed.., so that the column indexes are required to be get through a loop as well as footer column indexes are also required to be get through a loop.

Comment: ok.. so this approach will obviously not work. Even though the no. of columns is variable, do you know your datasource and what the column names will be?

Comment: I know the data source...,  But I don't know the column name  ..... the data source is  ....... DataTable dtQMaster = null;  dtQMaster = new DataBLL().summary(Param1, Parma2); 

            return dtQMaster;

Comment: Ok i have edited my answer.. not sure if it will work.. i have not tried it.. this is a new thing for me as I have never worked with variable number of columns and not knowing column names.. Hope this helps. This is an example for 1 column. If it works.. you can try for other columns similarly.

Comment: My first column is a serial number.... but...... Total Yes: 0 shown in the first column footer.... How to extend this to all footer columns